# How to install R on mac without admin rights

Tags: r, macos, installation, admin-rights

Looking to install R on my work machine, don't have the admin rights though and IT is not friendly to work with without business use-case so that's my last resort as it will likely fail.

I've attempted installing locally as this suggests.
https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/201152613-How-to-install-R-from-zip-without-admin-rights-

But no dice, it won't let me save the pkg in /usr/local/bin/: "Failed - Insufficient permissions".

Any one know of another way before I throw in the towel?

Cheers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Asked IT for local rights. They said yes :)